# Sum number in a character string (R)

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have a vector that looks like :

```
numbers <- c("1/1/1", "1/0/2", "1/1/1/1", "2/0/1/1", "1/2/1")
```

(not always the same number of "/" character)

How can I create another vector with the sum of the numbers of each string?

Something like :

```
sum
3
3
4
4
4
```

Comment: Also ```Reduce(`+`, data.table::tstrsplit(numbers, "/", fixed = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE, fill = 0))```

Comment: @DavidArenburg put this as an answer it is very elegant!

Answer (score 4):

One solution with `strsplit` and `sapply`:

```
sapply(strsplit(numbers, '/'), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
#[1] 3 3 4 4 4
```

`strsplit` will split your stings on `/` (doesn't matter how many `/`s you have). The output of `strsplit` is a list, so we iterate over it to calculate the sum with `sapply`.

Comment: Thank you for the speed and accurate answer, you save my day.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

What seems to me to be the most straightforward approach here is to convert your number strings to actual valid string arithmetic expressions, and then evaluate them in R using `eval` along with `parse`.  Hence, the string `1/0/2` would become `1+0+2`, and then we can simply evaluate that expression.

```
sapply(numbers, function(x) { eval(parse(text=gsub("/", "+", x))) })

1/1/1   1/0/2 1/1/1/1 2/0/1/1   1/2/1 
    3       3       4       4       4
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

**1) strapply** `strapply` matches each string of digits using `\\d+` and then applies `as.numeric` to it returning a list with one vector of numbers per input string.  We then apply `sum` to each of those vectors.  This solution seems particularly short.

```
library(gsubfn)

sapply(strapply(numbers, "\\d+", as.numeric), sum)
## [1] 3 3 4 4 4
```

**2) read.table** This applies `sum(read.table(...))` to each string.  It is a bit longer (but still only one line of code) but uses no packages.

```
sapply(numbers, function(x) sum(read.table(text = x, sep = "/")))
##   1/1/1   1/0/2 1/1/1/1 2/0/1/1   1/2/1 
##       3       3       4       4       4
```

Add the `USE.NAMES = FALSE` argument to `sapply` if you don't want names on the output.

`scan(textConnection(x), sep = "/", quiet = TRUE)` could be used in place of `read.table` but is longer.